# Remover elementos dinamicos con botones creados dinamicamente con jquery

Tags: jquery

Escribi el código con el cual creo elementos de forma dinámica, pero no se como implementar que el boton de remover que se crea junto a cada conjunto lo elimine.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  
  // CREAR
  $('#crear').on('click', function() {
    $('#elementos').append('<div class="form-row"><div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div><div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div><div class="col"><button class="remover btn btn-danger">Remover</button></div></div><br>');
  });
  
  //ELIMINAR
  
  //Esto es lo que no se hacer, una ayuda la agradeceria.
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="crear" class="btn btn-success">Crear</button>
<br><br>
<div id="elementos"></div>
```

Comment: No termino de entender, entonces el botón de remover debe o no aparecer?

Comment: Pienso que al momento de mandar a crear cada nuevo elemento, deberías asignarle un id. Para que así al pulsar sobre el botón Remover sepas a que id hace referencia y puedas así eliminar el mismo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes escuchar el `click` del boton eliminar, y con este buscar el `parent` de la clase especificada donde esta el elemento que agregaste.

Para que no salga un espacio en blanco cuando eliminas, ya que al termino de tu `append` agregas un `<br>`, le agregue un `margin:2px;` a cada elemento.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  
  // CREAR
  $('#crear').on('click', function() {
    $('#elementos').append('<div class="form-row" style="margin:2px;"><div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div><div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div><div class="col"><button class="remover btn btn-danger">Remover</button></div></div>');
  });
  
  //ELIMINAR
  $(document).on('click', '.remover', function(){
    $(this).parents('.form-row').remove();
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="crear" class="btn btn-success">Crear</button>
<br><br>
<div id="elementos"></div>
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: hacer referecia al `documento` para los cambios dinamicos
no haria que consuma mas recursos y sea aun mas lento entre mas grande sea la web?

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  
  // CREAR
  $('#crear').on('click', function() {
    $('#elementos').append('<div class="form-row separacion"><div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div><div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div><div class="col"><button class="remover btn btn-danger">Remover</button></div></div>');
  });
  
  // seleccionamos al padre  y utilizamos delegate
  // para buscar el elemento hijo con la clase remover 
  $("#elementos").on("click",".remover",function(e){
   // hacemos referencia al elemento clickeado con $(this)
   // luego buscamos a su padre div con clase form-row
    $(this).parents('.form-row').remove()
  // $(this).remove();
 })

});
```

```css
/*para evitar el uso de br*/
.separacion{
 margin-bottom:3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="crear" class="btn btn-success">Crear</button>
<br><br>
<div id="elementos"></div>
```